# usage of " wears as a badge of honor"

Tags: grammar

How can I understand the follow sentence

> He wears as a badge of honor the millions of dollars spent fluffing his image and importance as bulk-buyer of US weapons and like-minded strategic ally.

What is the main frame of this sentence? I thought it said he spent millions of dollars fluffing his image and importance to US?

I am confused about the usage of **wears as a badge of honor the millions of dollars**. Which word is the verb linking to importance?

Comment: A lot of money was spent building his image and reputation; he regards the amount of money as a *badge of honour*. If this doesn't make sense, the next step is for you to look up the meaning of "badge of honour". If, after that, the use of this expression still doesn't make sense, you can then [edit] your question to add what you learned about the expression and to pinpoint what you'd like explained further. :-)

Comment: This is a very 'verbose' phrase. Please add where it comes from to give some context.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is a bit out of standard order, probably because the direct object is so long.

> [He] [wears] [the millions of dollars spent fluffing his image and importance as bulk-buyer of US weapons and like-minded strategic ally] [as a badge of honor].

Answer (score 1):

> I am confused about the usage of "wears as a badge of honor the millions of dollars". and which word is the verb, linking to importance?

Well, the only verbs in that sentence are "wears" and "spent", but the expression "*wears as a badge of honour*" is *figurative*. The person being referred to is not literally *wearing* millions of dollars upon their person. The only verb *literally* linking to importance would have to be "spent".

A "badge of honour" would literally be a badge that you were awarded because of some achievement. You would wear such a badge as an outward display to others of your achievement, and the honour bestowed upon you for it.

Figuratively the expression "badge of honour" is used to describe anything that a person *outwardly displays to show their achievement*. In your example it sounds like someone spent a lot of money in a very showy way to show either how much money they had, or how important he was to have such an amount of money spent on him.

Answer (score 1):

The "Badge of Honor" is like when a warrior is wounded in battle. The bandage is not good, yet it may be seen as an honorable thing by some. So when someone takes a beating, even verbally, they may choose to say their actions was with good intentions, so the bad thing that happened was done with a good intention.

Answer (score 0):

> He wears as a badge of honor the millions of dollars spent fluffing his image and importance as bulk-buyer of US weapons and like-minded strategic ally.

What we have here is a good old-fashioned run-on sentence. If we break this down into several sentences, it should be clearer.

> Millions of dollars have been spent fluffing his image and importance.
>
> Millions of dollars have been spent bulk-buying US weapons.
>
> He is a like-minded strategic ally [of the US].
>
> He wears these actions as a badge of honour.

Finally, a badge of honour is an action or event that one is openly proud of; *"The veteran bore his scars like a badge of honour"*. *"My wife displays her stretch marks as a badge of honour"*.

The term can also be used critically, to imply that the person displaying the badge of honour should *not* be proud of the action. *"He thinks racism is a badge of honour"*. *"Criminals see prison time as a badge of honour."*

In this case, the writer is using the second sense. They are implying that the person in question is proud of actions that the writer thinks are reprehensible.

The meaning of the sentence, then, is that this person:

- Has spent millions of dollars;
- Has bought US weapons in bulk;
- Has developed a reputation as a strategic ally of the US;
- Has done these things to improve his own image and importance;
- And finally, this person is openly proud of these actions.